Unlock two LUKS devices before booting with clevis/initramfs
On Debian, how can I instruct clevis/initramfs to unlock two LUKS devices before booting?
I currently have both devices configured to be unlocked through TPM2, which is correctly configured as I can regenerate the bindings without having to provide the volume password.
~# clevis luks regen -d /dev/nvme0n1 -s 1
Regenerating binding (device /dev/nvme0n1, slot 1):
Pin: tpm2, Config: '{"hash":"sha256","key":"ecc","pcr_bank":"sha256","pcr_ids":"REDACTED"}'
Do you want to proceed? [ynYN] y
Binding regenerated successfully
~# clevis luks regen -d /dev/nvme1n1p3 -s 0
Regenerating binding (device /dev/nvme1n1p3, slot 0):
Pin: tpm2, Config: '{"hash":"sha256","key":"ecc","pcr_bank":"sha256","pcr_ids":"REDACTED"}'
Do you want to proceed? [ynYN] y
Binding regenerated successfully

Within the /etc/crypttab, both devices are listed and the UUID matches the crypto_LUKS devices in blkid. Using update-initramfs -u does not complain about missing references.
nvme0n1_crypt UUID=REDACTED none luks,discard
nvme1n1p3_crypt UUID=REDACTED  none luks,discard


However, whenever I boot only the second device nvme1n1p3_crypt is automatically decrypted without the first device being mentioned at all. After a while, the boot fails with the following message.
Please unlock disk nvme1n1p3_crypt:
cryptsetup: nvme1n1p3_crypt: set up successfully
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
   ...

(initramfs)

From there, I have to manually open the second device before proceeding.
(initramfs) cryuptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 nvme0n1_crypt
Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1: # Provided passphrase
(initramfs) exit
/dev/mapper/lab--vg-root: clean, REDACTED files, REDACTED blocks

The devices are set up as follow:
~# lsblk
NAME                                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1                             259:0    0 -----  0 disk  
└─nvme0n1_crypt                     252:1    0 -----  0 crypt 
  ├─lab--vg-data_tmeta              252:4    0 -----  0 lvm   
  │ └─lab--vg-data-tpool            252:6    0 -----  0 lvm   
  │   ├─lab--vg-data                252:7    0 -----  1 lvm    
  │   └─...                         252:22   0 -----  0 lvm   
  └─lab--vg-data_tdata              252:5    0 -----  0 lvm   
    └─lab--vg-data-tpool            252:6    0 -----  0 lvm   
      ├─lab--vg-data                252:7    0 -----  1 lvm   
      └─...                         252:22   0 -----  0 lvm   
nvme1n1                             259:1    0 -----  0 disk  
├─nvme1n1p1                         259:2    0 -----  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2                         259:3    0 -----  0 part  /boot
└─nvme1n1p3                         259:4    0 -----  0 part  
  └─nvme1n1p3_crypt                 252:0    0 -----  0 crypt 
    ├─lab--vg-root                  252:2    0 -----  0 lvm   /
    ├─lab--vg-swap_1                252:3    0 -----  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─lab--vg-data_tmeta            252:4    0 -----  0 lvm   
    │ └─lab--vg-data-tpool          252:6    0 -----  0 lvm   
    │   ├─lab--vg-data              252:7    0 -----  1 lvm   
    │   └─...                       252:22   0 -----  0 lvm   
    └─lab--vg-data_tdata            252:5    0 -----  0 lvm   
      └─lab--vg-data-tpool          252:6    0 -----  0 lvm   
        ├─lab--vg-data              252:7    0 -----  1 lvm  
        └─...                       252:22   0 -----  0 lvm

~# uname -a
Linux lab 6.8.12-4-pve #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PMX 6.8.12-4 (2024-11-06T15:04Z) x86_64 GNU/Linux


To have initramfs unlock arbitrary devices, the initramfs option can be used in the /etc/crypttab file.
nvme0n1_crypt UUID=REDACTED none luks,discard,initramfs
nvme1n1p3_crypt UUID=REDACTED  none luks,discard,initramfs

As per the crypttab(5) manual:

initramfs
The initramfs hook processes the root device, any resume devices and any devices with the initramfs option set. These devices are processed within the initramfs stage of boot. As an example, that allows the use of remote unlocking using dropbear.
This option is specific to the Debian crypttab format. It's not supported by systemd.

